# Merge PDF without saving a file on the disk

Tags: php, variables, pdf, merge

In php, after calling a webservice, I have some PDF content in variables.

I need to merge the pdf content in a single variable to make one single PDF and then post it to another webservice.

I found some solutions based on GS exec or FPDI but those solutions oblige me to save the files on the disk before merging it.

Is there a way to merge it in a variable without writing on the disk?

Code in Php (I have to merge the result of the foreach):

```
foreach($LogContent->DocumentsAnnexes->DocAnnexe as $parametre=>$value){
$content_brut=$value->fichier;
}
$content_maj=base64_decode($content_brut);
$OKMDocument->checkin(array('token' => $token, 'docPath' => $uuid, 'content' => $content_maj, 'comment' => 'Facture validée depuis le parapheur'));
```

(I can't add PDF example because of the size limit of the post)

Comment: could you give us an example of how the content is stored/structured?

Comment: Michael, edit your question to include the pdf-string content of those variables, we need to see them to know what we are dealing with here. If the content is not string, is it object? What type is it?

Comment: the PDF is in base64,
I take it from an object, I tried with (string) in front of the value, same result ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [stream wrapper](http://php.net/stream_wrapper) for variables (e.g. [this](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/miscellaneous/using-a-pdf-from-a-php-variable-instead-of-a-file/#question-76)) to overcome this issue.

Comment: No, in fact it doesn't work, i encourred thi issue : PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to find "startxref" keyword.' in /var/www/html/tests/soap_autre/vendor/setasign/fpdi/pdf_parser.php:287\nStack trace:

Comment: So, do you find the keyword "startxref" in the variable you pass to the stream wrapper?

Comment: I do not know how to find this, I send a binary file (in variable) to streamwrapper

$varInAnyScope[]=base64_decode((string) $value->fichier)

$this->setSourceFile(VarStream::createReference($file));

Comment: Both lines use independent variables. What do you want to tell me with this snippets?

Comment: Yes I don't write all the code
    $pdf = new ConcatPdf();
    $pdf->setFiles($varInAnyScope);
    $pdf->concat();

In the class Concat I change the path file with the VarStream

Do you need all the code ?

Comment: So I guess I understand what you are doing but you should create the reference outside of the ConcatPdf class. You should check the stream wrapper and how it works. It uses a REFERENCE (&) to a given variable. In your foreach-loop you will overwrite this variable, so the reference will also be overwritten.  Try something like `$files[$i]=base64_decode((string) $value->fichier); $filesByStreamWrapper[$i] = VarStream::createReference($files[$i]);` and then `$pdf->setFiles($filesByStreamWrapper);`

Comment: Stream wrapper appears to works only for one template. If I create loop to import multiple pdf files from wrapper, I get same template (last one) every time. I think it is related to closing stream on given example class on referenced page.

Comment: It should work for several templates. Anyhow just update to FPDI 2 and use the [native support](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/the-fpdi-class/#index-4) introduced in version 2.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this issue :

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This document
>   (VarStream://0) probably uses a compression technique which is not
>   supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI.

I tried to convert the PDF into 1.4 before merging with GhostscriptConverter :

```
class ConcatPdf extends FPDI
{
    public $files = array();

    public function setFiles($file)
    {
        $this->files = $file;
    }

    public function concat()
    {
        foreach($this->files AS $file) {

$command = new GhostscriptConverterCommand();
$filesystem = new Filesystem();

$converter = new GhostscriptConverter($command, $filesystem);
$converter->convert(VarStream::createReference($file), '1.4');




//            $pageCount = $this->setSourceFile($file);
            $pageCount = $this->setSourceFile(VarStream::createReference($file));
            for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {

                $tplIdx = $this->ImportPage($pageNo);
                $s = $this->getTemplatesize($tplIdx);
                $this->AddPage($s['w'] > $s['h'] ? 'L' : 'P', array($s['w'], $s['h']));
                $this->useTemplate($tplIdx);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But new issue :

> [Mon Nov 21 17:31:32.103668 2016] [:error] [pid 400] [client
>   192.168.21.2:53396] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'GPL Ghostscript 9.06: Unrecoverable
>   error, exit code 1\n' in
>   /var/www/html/tests/soap_autre/vendor/xthiago/pdf-version-converter/src/Converter/GhostscriptConverterCommand.php:39\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/tests/soap_autre/vendor/xthiago/pdf-version-converter/src/Converter/GhostscriptConverter.php(69):
>   Xthiago\PDFVersionConverter\Converter\GhostscriptConverterCommand->run('VarStream://0',
>   '/tmp/pdf_versio...', '1.4')\n#1
>   /var/www/html/tests/soap_autre/test.php(234):
>   Xthiago\PDFVersionConverter\Converter\GhostscriptConverter->convert('VarStream://0',
>   '1.4')\n#2 /var/www/html/tests/soap_autre/test.php(263):
>   ConcatPdf->concat()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in
>   /var/www/html/tests/soap_autre/vendor/xthiago/pdf-version-converter/src/Converter/GhostscriptConverterCommand.php
>   on line 39

I do not know what to do !

Comment: I guess Ghostscript will not work with stream wrappers, because it is called throug CLI. With the separate [FPDI PDF-Parser](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi-pdf-parser/details/) this problem should be gone, too.

Comment: Thanx for the tip, but it's commercial, do you know something free who can do that ?